# How to match two arrays

Tags: python, ironpython

I have two arrays

```
A = [a, b, c, d]
```

and

```
B = [a1, a2, b1, b2, b3, c1, c2, c3, d1, d2, d3, d4]
```

I want to match between the two arrays.

Match Result:

```
[a : a1, a2]
[b : b1, b2, b3]
[c : c1, c2, c3]
[d : d1, d2, d3, d4]
```

Comment: Are these lists of strings? If no, what are they? How does the matching occur? What do you want it to return?

Comment: Do you want Dictionary<string,List<string>> as result, where key is (a ,b,c e.t.c) and values are list of strings in which key is substring?

Comment: What kind of data structures are those?  They look kind of like lists.  Is `a` a literal value or a variable?

Comment: In Python this is an array: `array('c', 'hello world')` What you wrote are lists in Python. The only arrays in Python are here: (http://docs.python.org/library/array.html#module-array) Why are there tags **Python** an **C#** for your question ?

Comment: As already indicated, at the very least you'll have to specify what those `a`, `a1`, etc. are (are they strings? because the way you wrote them down, they're variables and you're better not confusing those with strings...) and what the heck `[a : a1, a2]` is supposed to be. If you want a dictionary, that's `{a: [a1, a1], b: ...}`

Comment: @eyquem Seeing that he's using IronPython, it would make sense that he could do this in Python or C#. I added the Python tag.

Comment: @NullUserException OK. It remains a question for me: is a code likely to be meaningfull both in C# and IronPython ? There are already faults in its code , but as soon as corrected, will it be meaningfull in C# ? His question is the kind of question very badly presented.

Answer (score 2):

In pretty Python:

```
di = {}
for item in A:
    di[item] = filter(lambda v: v.startswith(item), B)
```

Answer (score 1):

These solutions works fine both in `python` and `IronPython`.

**Imperative solution:**

```
A = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
B = ["a1", "a2", "b1", "b2", "b3", "c1", "c2", "c3", "d1", "d2", "d3", "d4"]

results = []

for prefix in A:
    matches = []
    results.append((prefix, matches))
    for el in B:
        if el.startswith(prefix):
            matches.append(el)

for res in results:
    print res
```

---

**Functional solution:**

```
A = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
B = ["a1", "a2", "b1", "b2", "b3", "c1", "c2", "c3", "d1", "d2", "d3", "d4"]

groups = [(x,[y for y in B if y.startswith(x)]) for x in A]
for group in groups:
    print group
```

---

**RESULT:**

```
('a', ['a1', 'a2'])
('b', ['b1', 'b2', 'b3'])
('c', ['c1', 'c2', 'c3'])
('d', ['d1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4'])
```

Comment: Why use a .NET `Dictionary`? Also, your "imperative solution" hurts my Python-accustomized eyes :(

Comment: @delnan: also added a functional solution and removed any c# dependency ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict

A = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
B = ["a1", "a2", "b1", "b2", "b3", "c1", "c2", "c3", "d1", "d2", "d3", "d4"]
d = defaultdict(list)
for item in B:
    prefix = item[0]
    if prefix in A:
        d[prefix].append(item)
```

Comment: No real need for a `defaultdict` here (nor for the `if`), because you know all the keys from the beginning, so you can just do `d = {key: [] for key in A}`. Still, this works correctly and efficiently so +1.

Comment: @Jochen Ritzel:  `defaultdict` and `if` were used in case the data sets were less well formed, such as `A = ['a','b','z']` and `B = ['a1','a2','b1','unexpected']`.

Comment: Downvoter, why?  Not cool to downvote a 1 1/2 year old answer and give no explanation.