# how to match 2 arrays ironpython or c#

Tags: c#, ironpython

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to match two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5044491/how-to-match-two-arrays)

I have 2 arrays

A = [good, bad, cat, frog]
and
B = [best, great, ill, evil, wicked, rotten, vicious, poor, nasty, puss, toad, paddock]

and I want to match between 2 arrays

Result
[good : best, great]
[bad : ill, evil, wicked, rotten, vicious, poor, nasty]
[cat : puss]
[frog : toad, paddock]

Comment: I don't understand how you derive the result, given the input. I can't discern a pattern...

Comment: maybe a FindSynonyms(string anyEnglishWord) method is the solution?

Comment: @rene: In what language is "okay" a synonym for "frog" and "set" a synonym for "boy"? And even the obviously related words (like "cat" and "tiger"/"lion"/"kitten") aren't *synonyms*. They're just related words that one might group together.

Comment: The frog was somehow puzzling me but I'm not too much into voodoo so I left it for the OP to clarify... We have to watch out that our comments are not banned and transferred to english.stackexchange.com...

Comment: @all: Mmh.. yesterday I answered to a question that is exactly the same excluding arrays content [(LINK)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5044491/how-to-match-2-arrays). But the user is different... sounds really suspicious to me...

Comment: Is this "homework"? Because it seems a silly problem :-)

Comment: @dig: Whoa, it's like there's a template to post ridiculous questions now. :/

Comment: @jeff: yes, and it smells also a bit trollish...

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
string[] roles = {"a", "e", "f", "h"};
string[] allRoles = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"};

foreach (string nextRole in allRoles) {
    if(Array.IndexOf(roles, nextRole) != -1)
    {
        Response.Write(nextRole + "<br/>");
    }
}
```